# Request blocked on azure waf when form fields have values as json strings

Tags: azure, web-application-firewall, amazon-waf

I have a form which has some input fields. Some of the input fields have json strings as values like

```
[{"actionItems":"1","actions":"Go To Home","articleLink":""}, 
{"actionItems":"2","actions":"Rollback","articleLink":""}]
```

But when I submit this the request gets blocked on azure WAF and gives 403. While the other forms that do not have json string as values are submitted successfully. Can someone suggest workaround for this.

Comment: Is the data being submitted using `<form>` or programatically with JS?

Comment: direct through <form>

Comment: Does it issue a POST or GET request upon submitting?

Comment: It issues a post

Answer (score 5):

I assume the reason WAF is filtering your request is because it detects a JSON payload while the `Content-Type` of the request is not `application/json`.

(The full list of rules is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/application-gateway-crs-rulegroups-rules?tabs=owasp31). From what I can see, such scenario can match multiple rules. My guess is *920120*, *920121* and *920341*)

You can either:

- `URLEncode` the data in your `<input>`
- Add a custom rule to disable WAF for the URL you're `POST`ing to
- Globally disable some of the rules that affecting this particular case
- Use JavaScript to programatically issue the request then set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.